# change text box based on selected option in drop down. Dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

We are trying to create a screen just like https://www.olark.com/extensions/targeting (click on "start a chat") has, but using json data.
we created most of the screen, but facing some problem.
we want to change text box when we select drop down.

for Example [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v597pv8c/3/)

In this demo when select "select3" from if condition then another text box will show. If we choose "select4" another text box will show as per in the olark.

We are not able to understnd what JSON modification is required and how we can do this.

```
  function initClickForAddRemove(){
$(".add").unbind().click(function(x){
    console.log($(this).closest("ul").attr("id"));
    var id=$(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
    //$('#'+id).append($("#"+id).clone());
    $("#"+id).clone(true, true).appendTo($("#"+id).parent());
});

$(".remove").unbind().click(function(x){
    console.log($(this).closest("ul").attr("id"));
    var id=$(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
    $("#"+id).remove();
    //$("#"+id).clone(true, true).appendTo($("#"+id).parent());
});
}
```